# Linking a your own library with native code on React Native

Tags: react-native

I build my own library for react-native and I want to make it available to the public. However, my library have some native implementation.

I want to use make the linking through react-native link avaialable, but I don't know how to start.

I have been looking on the [RPNM project](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/blob/1db2a06850f8f727b5c68ab0f3450f140c24ac91/README.md) but I can't figure how to add it.

Today I basically have to do everything manually. Adding the compile dependencies on the *build.gradle* files.

How to automate my library linking using react-native link?